# Connection is being keept alive using ssh2 in Node JS

Tags: node.js, ssh

I have built a function based on [this example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2), the objective is connect to a server or a router or a firewall via CLI. The connection and result are successful, but the connection is not being closed when the function `end()` is called.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2), the client method `end()` closes the connection and disconnect the socket.

> **end()** - (void) - Disconnects the socket.

This is the code:

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
var conn = new Client();

conn.on('ready', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error connecting... ' + err);
    }
    conn.exec(_command, function (err, stream) {
        stream.write(_command);
        if (err)
            console.log('Error executing command... ' + err);
        stream.on('data', function (data, stderr) {
            if (stderr)
                console.log('Error... ' + stderr);
            else {
                //some actions using the result string
            }
        }).on('exit', function (code, signal) {
            console.log('Exited with code ' + code);
            conn.end();
        });
        stream.end('\n');
    });
})
.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
}).on('end', function () {
    console.log('Client :: ended');
    conn.end();
})
.connect({
    host: _host,
    port: port,
    username: username,
    password: password
});
```

What is wrong or is there something missing?

Comment: Try a modern version of `ssh2`. The example and set of files you linked to are for an older, unsupported branch.

Comment: Additionally, the 'uptime' command does not read from stdin, so the `stream.write('uptime')` and `stream.end()` are unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks @mscdex I think I have the latest version of `ssh2`. for your second comment it's right what you said, it was only for an example, one of the commands that I'm executing is `show system info` in a firewall, for this I need to write the stream.

Comment: Can you verify the installed version of `ssh2` with `npm ls --depth=0`? The example code is still outdated, especially the `'data'` handler. stdout and stderr are now separate streams.

Comment: @mscdex I have updated the code using the example of the npm page module. The problem persists, thanks for your help.

Comment: @mscdex should I open an issue on github?